# improving a privacy tree barrier

Tags: landscaping, pines, privacy-plants

I have a row of 5 Blue Point Junipers, with 6ft spacing. I initially planted per guidelines, but learned later that I could reduce the spacing to create a wind/privacy barrier.

What I'd like to do is add 4 more junipers in between to create a privacy barrier. Will this be possible with the initial row already being 10ft tall, using 3ft saplings for the addition?

**Update**

I'm working with the area between the fence and the brick. 3'-4' wide. I should be able to fit a 1' stagger here

[image: current tree line]

Comment: How wide is the planting area? And is it important to you to have them in a straight line, or would planting in two staggered rows be acceptable?

Comment: The row is along a privacy fence. The plantable area is about 3' width

Comment: I've updated with a photo.

Comment: @Ian  I would get rid of that edging. You could also do a second staggered row very easily of 3 '.    In fact I would be making a plant bed at the base of these junipers that  undulates with regular radius curves to have a thick bed of mixed species.  Lawn looks best with definite large curves then a trench and then 'raised beds' for plants.  The best edge is a 6X6" trench at the foot of the bed between the lawn and bed.  Big steady radius curves...not the concrete which stands out too much.

Comment: @stormy Taking the edging out and staggering 3' was thought of already. The look on the wifes face when I mentioned it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: beginning of new fence]Absolutely!  Don't put them in the same line if you can possibly do this...make another row, offset from the first at a minimum of 2 feet, 3 feet would be better.  You should have equilateral triangles between 2 in the back and one in the front row, the new row.

Making a row offset in front of your original row will give reason to the height difference as well as plugging up the gaps.  This gives each plant plenty of room to grow symmetrically and fully.  Your original shrubs should be topped to the height you are easily able to maintain.  That will help them to grow outwards versus upwards.  Become denser.  Just brush the tips on the sides and make sure the bottom of the shrub is wider than the top.

Have you fertilized?  A tree stake of balanced fertilizer works great for a year.  If you've already fertilized how long ago and with what formulation?  Compost is not fertilizer.  Does have some nitrogen but you need a balanced fertilizer.  Are your new shrubs in pots or B and B?

[image: Privacy fence that allows air and light through[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHzRM.jpg)

A picture of a similar privacy screen.  Neighbor's garbage is behind this screen.  Solid fences make you feel like you are in a cat box.  These screens with the 2X2's lap [image: Privacy fence without the cat box feeling]jointed into regular squares are also amenable for a great vine.  This would be an alternative to the staggered rows...Use hops, or Akebia quinata?  Need to know where you live for better suggestions.

Comment: I've seen the pattern on some websites, but not sure if I can go this route with the space I have available. I may be able to move about a foot from center. is it needed to stagger?

Comment: Stagger is the right word.  A foot off center is better than nothing.  Staggering is the way I plant all hedges, really all plants.  Pulling the front row out as far as possible is best but even a foot off center will make your new plants look a part of the whole and give each plant more room to fill out.  This method also doesn't make a glaring hole if one plant dies.  How is the health of your existing plants?  Have you considered a screen made of lumber?

Comment: I'm in a rural area, so am restricted on what I can install. I use evergreen stakes annually and they have been in pretty good health. We did have an issue in the beginning with an old neighbor using *cides heavily and we had to replace one on the end.

Comment: Great for the fert!  Rural areas are a bit more relaxed than developments in or near the city.  Are you in an HOA?  These screens don't even have to be in a straight line...I stagger them as well.  Are there any problems with 'line of sight' onto the road from the drive that this would hamper?  Neighbor's usually LOVE this screen solution, a win win thing.  Sorry about the controlling neighbor but this would go a long ways to making a positive thing between your homes.

Comment: Edge of suburbs/rural area. City still controls fencing in our area. No HOA, thankfully. The screen is something to think about in the future; I'm a homebrewer, so hops is part of the garden.

Comment: Really?  I love hops!  My favorite is Golden...or Sun something or other but I've never made beer.  Hops will cover these screens completely every spring.  In the early spring I tear off all the dead vines and very very soon it is covered completely with hops.  These screens are amazing how they improve the value of your home way above doing the hedge.